# Using the Search widget with a Dynamic Map Service Layer

Tags: arcgis, arcgis-server

I'm trying to see if there is a way to use a dynamic map service layer as a source for the Search Widget provided in the ArcGis Javascript API. As far as I can see from the documentation, only feature layers are supported.

Is there some sort of work around? Potentially using Locators?